# set labels or text left Android hoirontalbarchart

Tags: android, xml, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

So I am looking for a solution still on how to get any text on the left side of the bar chart. 
The libary I am using is the MpAndroidChart.

XML:

```
 <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.HorizontalBarChart
                android:id="@+id/barchart"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"></com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.HorizontalBarChart>
```

Java:

```
BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(data(),null);
        barDataSet.setColor(getResources().getColor(bars));
        BarData barData = new BarData( barDataSet);
        YAxis yAxisRight = barChart.getAxisRight();
        yAxisRight.setEnabled(false);

        barChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
        barChart.animateY(1000);
        barChart.invalidate();
        barChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);

        XAxis xAxis = barChart.getXAxis();
        xAxis.setEnabled(false);

        barChart.setData(barData);
 private ArrayList<BarEntry> data(){
        ArrayList<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
        entries.add(new BarEntry(7,7));
        entries.add(new BarEntry(6,6));
        entries.add(new BarEntry(5,5));
        entries.add(new BarEntry(4,4));
        entries.add(new BarEntry(3,3));
        entries.add(new BarEntry(2,2));
        entries.add(new BarEntry(1,1));
        return entries;
    }
```

Right now it looks like this:
[image]
but I want on the left of every bar a label or text.

thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering the answer is actually pretty simple:

```
  XAxis xAxis = barChart.getXAxis();
        //xAxis.setEnabled(false);
        xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        final String[] week = {"S","S","F","T","W","T","M"};
        IndexAxisValueFormatter formatter = new IndexAxisValueFormatter(week);
        xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
        xAxis.setValueFormatter(formatter);
```